# Cannot debug in Xcode: Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, firebase

Debugging in Xcode is not possible after adding Firebase.

You cannot execute commands with **expr** and there is no variable information viewable.

Firebase was integrated without Cocoapods using these directions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

Here's what Xcode displays after trying to execute a command with **expr**:

```
warning: Swift error in module Test.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'Test' from AST context:
error: missing required module 'Firebase'
```

We're using Swift 3.

Comment: can you add your pod file code also.

Comment: we didn't install via cocoapods @SatishBabariya

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was not updating **User Header Search Paths** with the directory containing **module.modulemap**.

Here are the instructions, accidentally overlooked, for manual installation:

> If you're using Swift, or you want to use modules, drag
>   module.modulemap into    your project and update your User Header
>   Search Paths to contain the    directory that contains your module
>   map.

The other hiccup was recognizing the correct directory path since we used groups to organize files, not folders.

May someone else benefit from our stupidity! :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug of Xcode. i am facing the same problem. After some researches i found that this happens because of bad code, especially when you use closures. It is being reported as xcode bug, but there are some ways to fix it. Use print("") for debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your modules like Firebase to your test-scheme in your podfile

### Cocoapods

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'yourApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for yourApp
  pod 'Alamofire', '4.4.0'
  pod 'Firebase', '4.3.0'

  target 'yourAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'Firebase', '4.3.0'
  end

end
```

---

### Manualy added

(I'm not 100% sure if this works)

1. Click on you Projekt in Xcode (the very first listpoint in your project)
2. Select at the Targets your test-target (yourAppTests)
3. Search for "other link" at 'Build Settings'
4. add to "Other Linker Flags"

   1. -ObjC
   2. -framework
   3. "GoogleToolboxForMac"
   4. -framework
   5. "nanopb"

Comment: we didn't install via cocoapods.

Comment: oh okay x) than make sure that the lib is also "connected" to your test-scheme

Comment: it depends on how you installed the lib

Comment: we followed the firebase "integrate without cocoa-pods" instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was using XCode 9. I spend 2 hours searching for the solution then someone suggested me, I should run my code on XCode 10 (I'm still using XCode beta). It worked.

Hope that helps!!.