# Batched Writes - When Does The OnSuccess Method Reached?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have read the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/transactions) about the `batched writes`, but I didn't understand when does the `onSuccess` method is reached:

1. After all of the writes were executed.
2. After all of the writes were completed.
3. After all of the writes were successfully completed.

Or none of the above...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A batch write is atomic and so it will either successfully complete *all* of the writes, or it will fail *all* of the writes.

So once the batch write completes, it will call the `onSuccess()` method if it was successful and all writes were committed, or it will call the `onFailure()` method if it was not successful and none of the writes were committed.

Comment: hi michael firebase is awesome, but it seems to interfere with debugging in xcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675100/cannot-debug-in-xcode-debug-info-from-this-module-will-be-unavailable-in-the-de/46829887#46829887. is this a known issue?

Comment: Wow, our answers have exactly the same timestamp!

Answer (score 3):

The [`WriteBatch#commit()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/WriteBatch#commit()) method, like other Firestore write and read operations, spawns and returns a [`Task`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) instance that will perform the work in the background.

Success listeners attached to this `Task` will be called if the task completes successfully. It's a bit like attaching a complete listener and then checking that the task result was successful.

In the case of `BatchWrite`, all of the writes in the batch are committed as a single atomic unit, so will only return success if all of the writes were successful.